# Encrypt message with C++ without libraries

Tags: c++, encryption

I want to encrypt message in a simple way using C++, so I've written this function:

```
char* encrypt(char* not_encrypted){

    char* encrypted = new char[strlen(not_encrypted)];
    char* begin = encrypted;

    while (*not_encrypted != '\0') {

        *encrypted = *not_encrypted + 3;

        not_encrypted++;
        encrypted++;

    }

    encrypted = '\0';

    return begin;
}
```

But it didn't work as I expected. 
Here is an example of it's work:

Enter string: asf

dvi

^pc

I'm wondering where I made a mistake.

Comment: `encrypted = '\0';`?

Comment: It is not a good idea to return a raw pointer to dynamically allocated memory. Actually it is a bad idea.

Comment: Also please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: I think with GCC 7.2.0, the `encrypted = '\0';` line would even fail to compile.  I've seen a few bugs that were discovered this way.

Answer (score 2):

Using the style you used in your question, this might get you what you want:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

char* encrypt(const char* not_encrypted)
{
   char* encrypted = new char[strlen(not_encrypted) + 1];
   char* begin = encrypted;

   while (*not_encrypted != '\0')
   {
      *encrypted++ = *not_encrypted++ + 3;
   }
   *encrypted = '\0';

   return begin;
}

int main()
{
   const char plaintext[] = "This is my plaintext.";
   char *ciphertext = NULL;

   ciphertext = encrypt(plaintext);
   std::cout << "Plaintext:  \"" << plaintext << "\"" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Ciphertext: \"" << ciphertext << "\"" << std::endl;
   delete ciphertext; ciphertext = NULL;
}
```

Note that I've made two important changes:

1. Add one to `strlen(not_encrypted)` for sizing your `encrypted`
   buffer (this is to give room for the '\0' null-terminator character
   in the output), and
2. Dereference `encrypted` when assigning the null-terminator ('\0').

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me. I should've been more careful with pointers.